# Is the Playstation VR headset region-locked?

Tags: playstation-vr

I'm going to be buying a Playstation VR headset from the USA. Will it work with my European PS4?

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can use a EU Playstation 4 and a US Playstation VR. However do make sure that you have an adapter for the difference in the US and EU power cables.

A few sources:

https://www.reddit.com/r/PSVR/comments/4vsvao/will_there_be_a_region_code_for_the_psvr/

https://www.quora.com/Can-I-use-PlayStation-VR-Launch-Bundle-in-other-countries